# Setting a Symfony2 Entity form field using it's id

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a Symfony2 unmapped form which has a field of type 'Entity'. Here is the form type definition:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('RegistrationForgotEmailTemplate', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'EmailBundle:EmailTemplate',
            'placeholder' => '-- Default ---',
        ));
}
```

Here is where I build the form instance:

```
$data = array('RegistrationForgotEmailTemplate' => 4);
$form = $this->createForm($formType, $data, array(
            'action' => $url,
            'method' => 'POST'
            ));
```

My problem is the form is not setting the RegistrationForgotEmailTemplate field to the correct entity (id 4). I assume this is because I am providing the id of the entity rather than an instance of it. Is there a way of providing the just the id of the entity to set this field or is the only way to pass an instance of the entity I want to set the field to?

Comment: what about add a field of type "text" ?

Comment: Use [DataTransformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use a transformer or you could use the "choice" field rather than "entity" and inject an object to provide the choices list (likely a repository).

Personally I think you'll find the transformer method easier. The resulting code will be nicer too

Comment: I did look at using a "choice" field but didn't like the idea of injecting the choices. Transformer looks like a much nicer solution, I'll give that a go. Thanks :D